# iOS aws sdk v2 resume issue append data

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager

Hi I'm using aws sdk v2

for download I'm using 
ASWSS3Transfermanager and AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest

problem scenario is as follows:

1. user download file.
2. file total size is 500MB but user download until 200MB and exit app.
3. Check the result 200MB file remains well.
4. relaunch app and start download same file, aws sdk start download since 0MB.

How can i download file since 200MB??
Is there a way to save AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest??

please help me..

Answer (score 0):

While the app relaunched, If you re-create the `AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest` again (even with same parameters) and create a download task via`ASWSS3TransferManager`, your previously download task will be lost and new download will be initialized.

To resume your previously download, there are two options:

1. When the app relaunched, call the `resumeAll` instead of recreating a new `AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest`:

`[AWSS3TransferManager resumeAll:nil] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
   //process your task.result
}];`

2. Using `AWSS3TransferUtility` instead of `AWSS3TransferManager` in latest AWS Mobile SDK for iOS. The `AWSS3TransferUtility` will utilize  Apple's Background Transfer feature so that the download task will continue even the app has been shutdown.